# Disable dropdown if checkbox is checked in reactjs using typescript

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, dropdown

I have disabled the dropdown by default. The dropdown should be enabled only when the checkbox is checked. Please let me know, what is the best approach for this. I using reactjs app and coding done in typescript.

Comment: Can you please add the code and mention that what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1):

Before post a question:

- provide some code,
- describe what problem you are facing,
- and what you have tried so far,
- and what's the expected.

---

Here is a demo for `disable once checked`

```js
const App = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(true);
  const onChangeHandler = () => {
    setChecked(!checked);
    setStatus(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value={checked}
        disabled={!status}
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, it’s a very simple requirement. I have explained pretty simple way. As I am new to reactjs, hence I am asking what will be the best approach. I have'nt tried anything yet. I hope this much is enough to suggest my request. 
To be more precise on the requirement, one checkbox and dropdown is there. I need to enable dropdown to select only when the checkbox is checked.